# how does google verify ownership of a website?

Tags: web, verification

In order to verify that I own a website, google asked me to do the following:

> 1. Download this HTML verification file. [googleXXX.html]
> 2. Upload the file to http://www.example.com/
> 3. Confirm successful upload by visiting http://www.example.com/googleXXX.html in your browser.
> 4. Click Verify below.
>
> To stay verified, don't remove the HTML file, even after verification succeeds.

The file provided by google contains a single line:

```
google-site-verification: googleXXX.html
```

How that this work? How is that supposed to tell them that I actually own that domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't tell them that you own it, it tells them that you have write permission to it.  That's considered enough.

Comment: They look to see whether you successfully placed the file on the website, and they consider you verified if they find it there.  If they get a 404, they don't consider you verified.  "how can they tell?" - by looking at http://www.example.com/googleXXX.html

Comment: ok I thought the verification was done at step 3, which now seems to be useless.

Comment: @MajidL: I think Step 3 is just for you to check that the upload has worked.

Answer (score 1):

It demonstrates that you have sufficient control of the web server at the domain to be able to add pages to the website.  The assumption is that this level of control would only be available to the owner of the domain, or a delegated administrator.